# What does "available" modify in the sentence below?

Tags: modifiers

> There are 500 kg of this material available in our stocks.

In this sentence does the ''available'' modify '' 500 kg. of this material '' or only ''material''? I thought it modifies ''500 kg. of this material ''but I couldn't be sure. I mean should it be thought as;

> There are (500 kg of this material) + (available) in our stocks.

Or

> There are 500 kg of this (material )+(available) in our stocks.

Comment: You need to fix some spelling or typing errors in your question. Also no dot needed after 'kg'.

Answer (score 1):

It modifies the whole phrase "500 kg. of material". It specifies that there is that much of it available.

Answer (score 0):

I think your first phrase does not leave ambiguity about the fact that *available* modifies your *500 kg of this material*. The structure *There is so much of something available* is rather common.

If the speaker wished *available* to modify only *material*, he would have probably said

> There are 500 kg of this material, ***which is*** available in our stocks.

It would help this sentence sound more natural, if something more particular was said about the 500 kg

> ***Here*** are 500 kg of this material, which is available in our stocks.

or

> ***You can buy up to*** 500 kg of this material, which is available in our stocks.